# I need to build a mass emailing app which sends one email every 7 seconds from the list to avoid emails getting spammed

Tags: php, swiftmailer

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Setup host and Port

$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl'))
->setUsername('any@any.com')
->setPassword('any')
;



$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Test Subject'))
->setFrom(['estesys53@gmail.com' => 'JSebastian Smith'])
->setTo(['any@gmail.com', 'any@any.com', 
's.any@stu.any.edu' => 'Sebastian'])
->setBody('Here is the test message itself')
;

// Send the message

$result = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

My code is working fine but sending all emails at once to addresses provided in ->setto variable. I need to set up a loop which does a time delay of sending one email every 7 sec.

Comment: Have you tried to make the loop already?

Comment: So you'll have a client that will timeout when you have over a certain number of email addresses?  Are you sure php is the way you want to go?

Comment: @Archer this can be a console script, not necessary a web one

Comment: @Cid Yes, which is why I've asked the OP the question.

Comment: I am forced to use PHP by the client, However I am new to the language :)

Answer (score -1):

1. [Loop over the addresses using `for each`.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) In each loop:

   1. Send an email to one address, using the code you provided.
   2. [Wait 7 seconds using `sleep`.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Break down your problems and work out how to do each part. Then problems become much easier.

Comment: "Break down your problems and work out how to do each part. Then problems become much easier."  This is the essence of programming.

Comment: @ivanivan Do _you_ have a clue why this was downvoted?

Comment: Answers with links are fine, but if it's just links then it's pretty pointless.  Relevant code should be in the answer.

Comment: @Archer It's links to documentation, not code. It's to teach the asker how to solve this problem. They're purely auxiliary; the answer stands without them. I added them in afterwards.

Comment: We can disagree about the validity or value of your links all day, but as I also said `Relevant code should be in the answer.`  This answer is of no value once those links don't work.

Comment: @Archer I see what you're saying; sorry for being so slow on the uptake. Better? Now the links add _absolutely_ nothing except convenience, as they should.

Answer (score -2):

Create PHP script that takes next email and sends it.
Set up Cron/Task Scheduler to run this script every 7 seconds.